# Update local sqlite db windows phone 8 application

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I am new to **windows phone 8** development and I have developed a **windows phone 8** application and it is live on the store. 
But now I am facing a problem. My application uses **sqlite db** stored locally. The app uses the database to show data.

But now when ***I update the database and upload the build on the store and after updating the app on the device the app still shows the old data and didnt update the database***.It shows the same data as it was when the app first installed on the device.

How can I overcome this thing, It is a major issue which I need to solve in order to update my app. The app when updates on the device should show the latest database records but it is not showing them right now. Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:**
From Official Documentation,

> When an app is updated in the Store, its local folder is not touched
>   or modified. It is your responsibility to make sure the data is
>   migrated or transformed appropriately to work with the new version of
>   the app.

So what you can do is rename the database and update the app with renamed database.Then on first run copy the new database to isolated folder and then perform a check to detect if your previous database exists or not - if exists then delete that database to save space.